# Average of grouped rows in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, average

I have an Sql Server Table.. it's something like this:

`````````````````````````````````
Id ...... Column1 ...... Column2  
````````````````````````````````  
1 ........ 1 ............. 34  
2 ........ 1 ............. 44  
3 ........ 2 ............. 45  
4 ........ 2 ............. 36  
5 ........ 2 ............. 23  
6 ........ 3 ............. 68  
7 ........ 3 ............. 26
`````````````````````````````````

So, I need to select the average of Column2,but group with column1 before doing that.
I mean, if I say Avg(Column2) it just returns a single row with the average of all rows.

What I need is, first i need to group them by column so:
Average of column2 where column1 = 1
Average of column2 where column1 = 2
Average of column2 where column1 = 3

So I want 3 rows returned with the averages of respective values of column1. I am lost at doing this, any hints / help please?

ps: I tried several related questions, and none of them helped / I couldn't understand.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select column1, avg(column2) from table group by column1
```

Answer (score 4):

simple

```
select AVG(Column2) from table group by Column1
```

doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT column1, AVG(column2) 
  FROM "Insert table name"
GROUP BY column1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Column1, AVG(Column2) FROM test GROUP BY Column1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This following Query will help for Calculate the average value of a ROW:

```
 select Avg(A.Tamil + A.English + A.Maths + A.Science + A.Social_Science)/5 As 
 Average
 from MarkTable A, MarkTable B, MarkTable C
 where A.RollNo='14UCA002'
```

This might helpful...

Answer (score -1):

Execute the following SQL from average :

```
select column1,avg(column2) from tablename group by column1;
```