# SQL query averaging by name

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have this below data:

```
    criteria    rating

    Criteria1   3
    Criteria2   3
    Criteria3   3
    Criteria5   3
    Criteria1   5
    Criteria2   5
    Criteria3   5
    Criteria5   1
```

i want to take average of rating each by criteria name like :

expected output:

```
    criteria    rating

    Criteria1   4
    Criteria2   4
    Criteria3   4
    Criteria5   2
```

Can anybody help me achieving that?

Comment: What was the problem? Simple `Group By` & `Avg` will do the work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Average of grouped rows in Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100921/average-of-grouped-rows-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

```
Select criteria, avg(rating) as rating from tbl group by criteria
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work:

```
SELECT criteria, AVG(rating) FROM <table_name>
GROUP BY criteria;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Criteria, 
        AVG(rating) 
             From YourTable 
             GROUP BY Criteria 
             ORDER BY Criteria
```